# How can I write tests for file upload in PHP?

Tags: php, unit-testing, upload, file-upload, simpletest

I'm using simpleTest to write my PHP tests. I'm writing a file upload plugin and was wondering how I may be testing it.

I would like to check that the file is correctly uploaded, in the right folder, that error are correctly returned when needed, etc.

How do I emulate a file upload (through the $_FILES variable) ? Are there any issues I should be aware of ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've found an alternate solution. I've spoofed the `$_FILES` array with test data, created dummy test files in the `tmp/` folder (the folder is irrelevant, but I tried to stick with the default).

The problem was that `is_uploaded_file` and `move_uploaded_file` could not work with this spoofed items, because they are not really uploaded through `POST`.
First thing I did was to wrap those functions inside my own `moveUploadedFile` and `isUploadedFile` in my plugin so I can mock them and change their return value.

The last thing was to extends the class when testing it and overwriting `moveUploadedFile` to use `rename` instead of `move_uploaded_file` and `isUploadedFile` to use `file_exists` instead of `is_uploaded_file`.

Comment: Expanding this answer with how to mock the moving of files in move_uploaded_file would be very helpful.

Comment: @pixelastic Any chance you could show us your code for that?

Comment: Unfortunately this question is more than 7 years old and I don't have access to this code anymore (plus, there was so many major PHP versions since then I don't think my code would still work).

Answer (score 9):

According to the Docs, [SimpleTest has support for FileUpload testing baked in since version 1.0.1:](http://simpletest.org/en/overview.html)

```
File upload testing     Can simulate the input type file tag    1.0.1
```

I've looked over the examples at their site and would assume you'd use something along the lines of

```
$this->get('http://www.example.com/');
$this->setField('filename', 'local path');
$this->click('Go');
```

to submit the file and then use the regular assertions to check the upload worked as wanted. But that's really just a wild guess, since I am not familiar with SimpleTest and I couldnt find an example at their homepage. You might want to [ask in their support forum though.](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=simpletest-support)

But basically, there is not much use testing that a form uploads a file. This is tried and tested browser behavior. Testing the code that handles the upload makes more sense. I dont know how you implemented your FileUpload code, but if I had to implement this, I would get rid of the dependency on the `$_FILES` array as the first thing. Create a `FileRequest` class that you can pass the `$_FILES` array to. Then you can handle the upload from the class. This would allow you to test the functionality without actually uploading a file. Just setup your FileRequest instance accordingly. You could even mock the filesystem with [vfsStreamWrapper](http://code.google.com/p/bovigo/wiki/vfsStream), so you dont even need actual files.

Comment: I want to be able to test only small fractions of my plugin. Doing a whole get request won't get me the level of detail I need.

Answer (score 5):

You can generate a file upload in a programmatic manner with e.g. the [curl](http://php.net/curl) extension.

Since this requires PHP running under a web server, it's not much of a unit test. Consequently, the best way would be to to use PHPT tests and fill the [`--POST_RAW--` section](http://qa.php.net/phpt_details.php#post_raw_section) with the data.

If you don't know what to put in the `--POST_RAW--`, try to install the TamperData Firefox extension, do a file submission from Firefox, and copy-paste the data from the right side.

Comment: As you said, cURL is not so good for unit testing. I read the PHPT documentation and I think that may be the better solution. Unfortunatly I did not managed to get it to work... I finally found an other solution (see my answer)

Comment: I also tried using PHPT and --POST_RAW-- but couldn't get it to work either, as documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974727/phpt-unable-to-run-sample-tests-that-use-post-raw

Answer (score -2):

For unit testing (as opposed to functional testing) try uploading a file (a short text file) to a test page, and `var_dump($_FILES)` and `var_dump($_POST)`. Then you know what to populate them (or your mocks) with.

Comment: is_uploaded_file will still fail

Comment: But why? What is is_uploaded_file() looking for? Kind of dumb that this cannot be easily mocked.