# PHPT - Unable to run sample tests that use --POST_RAW--

Tags: php, unit-testing, post, phpunit, phpt

This .PHPT test completes: [(from PHPT docs)](http://qa.php.net/write-test.php)

File: `strtr.phpt`

```
--TEST--
strtr() function - basic test for strstr()
--FILE--
<?php
/* Do not change this test it is a README.TESTING example. */
$trans = array("hello"=>"hi", "hi"=>"hello", "a"=>"A", "world"=>"planet");
var_dump(strtr("# hi all, I said hello world! #", $trans));
?>
--EXPECT--
string(32) "# hello All, I sAid hi planet! #"
```

`$ pear run-tests --cgi strtr.phpt`

Output:

```
Running 1 tests
PASS strtr() function - basic test for strstr()[uploadTest.phpt]
TOTAL TIME: 00:00
1 PASSED TESTS
0 SKIPPED TESTS
```

However, when I try running another example test, like [`sample006.phpt`](http://qa.php.net/sample_tests/sample006.php), and any other test that uses `--GET--`, `--POST--`, `--POST_RAW--`, etc., sections, the tests always fail.

My Big Picture Goal is to test file uploads in PHPUnit by way of PHPT as described in [Testing file uploads with PHP](http://qafoo.com/blog/013_testing_file_uploads_with_php.html). The `--POST_RAW--` example used in that article fails for me as well, whereas the other examples pass successfully.

It would appear I have a local config problem, but I have no idea where I would track this down. Not much in Google, unfortunately.

One thing I've noticed between these `--POST--` tests failing, and other regular tests failing, is that the regular test failures always populate the `*.out` file with the failed output of the script. The `--POST--` tests that fail do not have anything in the `*.out` file, even when I am explicitly outputting text.

Do those example PHPT tests using `--POST_RAW--` work for anyone else?

Here are my system specs: (php 5.2, os x 10.6)

```
$ pear -V
PEAR Version: 1.9.1
PHP Version: 5.2.13
Zend Engine Version: 2.2.0
Running on: Darwin mbp.local 10.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.6.0: Wed Nov 10 18:13:17 PST 2010; root:xnu-1504.9.26~3/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

Comment: The test fails for me as well on PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.7 with PEAR 1.9.1. :(

Comment: Try running it with `php run-tests.php /path/to/test.phpt`. You will have to set the `TEST_PHP_CGI_EXECUTABLE` env variable (or something to that effect) before.

Comment: the --cgi flag i believe is what is required, but i will look into that env var as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the PHP CGI version for those tests to work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the php-cgi executable to the --cgi option. Something like this

pear run-tests --cgi=/usr/bin/php-cgi strtr.phpt
or
pear run-tests --cgi=php-cgi strtr.phpt

I spent nearly a day trying to figure this out, when I read the pear help run-tests documentation it makes sense now but at the time I completely glossed over the fact that it wanted the executable.