# Test move_uploaded_file and is_uploaded_file with vfsStream

Tags: php, unit-testing, file, tdd, phpunit

I've tried to test move_uploaded_file and is_uploaded_file with PHPUnit and vfsStream. They always return false.

```
public function testShouldUploadAZipFileAndMoveIt()
{
    $_FILES = array('fieldName' => array(
        'name'     => 'file.zip',
        'type'     => 'application/zip',
        'tmp_name' => 'vfs://root/file.zip',
        'error'    => 0,
        'size'     => 0,
    ));

    vfsStream::setup();
    $vfsStreamFile = vfsStream::newFile('file.zip');
    vfsStreamWrapper::getRoot()
        ->addChild($vfsStreamFile);

    $vfsStreamDirectory = vfsStream::newDirectory('/destination');
    vfsStreamWrapper::getRoot()
        ->addChild($vfsStreamDirectory);

    $fileUpload = new File_Upload();
    $fileUpload->upload(
        vfsStream::url('root/file.zip'),
        vfsStream::url('root/destination/file.zip')
    );

    $this->assertFileExists(vfsStream::url('root/destination/file.zip'));
}
```

Is it possible? How do I do that?
Can I post a vfsStreamFile (or any data) without a form, just using PHP code?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No. `move_uploaded_file` and `is_uploaded_file` are specifically designed to handle uploaded files. They include extra security checks to ensure that the file's not been **tampered** with in the time between the upload completing and the controlling script accessing the file.

Note: changing the file from within the script counts as tampering.

Comment: No idea, actually. I've never used phpunit. There's some stuff here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402765/how-can-i-write-tests-for-file-upload-in-php  though not specifically for phpunit.

Comment: @user972959 try isolating move_uploaded_file on other function, mock that function implementing copy + file_exists instead

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using classes you can create a parent class.

```
// this is the class you want to test
class File {
  public function verify($file) {
    return $this->isUploadedFile($file);
  }
  public function isUploadedFile($file) {
    return is_uploaded_file($file);
  }
}

// for the unit test create a wrapper that overrides the isUploadedFile method
class FileWrapper extends File {
  public function isUploadedFile($file) {
    return true;
  }
}

// write your unit test using the wrapper class
class FileTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  public function setup() {
    $this->fileObj = new FileWrapper;
  }

  public function testFile() {
    $result = $this->fileObj->verify('/some/random/path/to/file');
    $this->assertTrue($result);
  }
}
```