# Imitating file upload in a form while testing with CakePHP

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, tdd, phpunit

I'm developing a PHP application where I have a form in which the user should upload a text file and an other page works with this data. I'm also creating controller tests with CakePHP and PHPUnit. My question is, how can I make the test automatically upload a file for the tests of this action?
Thanks in advance.

update 1:
The question in more details: Basically I have a 'submit' action which has the form in its view which submits the parameters (and the uploaded file) to the 'curl' action. Here this curl action processes the uploaded text file and **this is** actually what I'd like to test. But to test this, I should have an uploaded file with its content, so a more specific question: how could I mock this uploaded file to 'submit' it to my curl controller?

Code snippet for the View:

```
...
echo '<fieldset><table>';
echo $this->Form->create('Job', array('type' => 'post','action' => 'curl', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));

echo $this->Form->input('user.name', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $this->User->getCode1(),'name' => 'user.name'));
echo $this->Form->input('class', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $this->Hadoop->getClass(), 'name' => 'class'));
...
```

update 2:
The test I've already written:

```
public function testCurl() {

    $data = array(
        'user_name' => ...,
        'release' => ...,
        'analysis_period_start' => ...,
        'uploaded_file' => ???
    );

    $Jobs = $this->generate('Jobs', array('components' => array('Session')));
    $Jobs->Session->expects($this->any())->method('setFlash');
    $this->testAction('/jobs/curl', array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'post'));

}
```

So basically I'm trying to test my curl action with a POST method with the data provided in the $data variable. But I don't know how to mock/imitate an uploaded file into that array.

update 3:
The relevant cod snippet from my controller's given action:

```
public function curl() {
    /* This action accepts only POST request */
    if (!$this->isPOSTRequest())
        return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'jobs', 'action' => 'submit'));

    /* Create a new entry in the database and get its ID */
    $id = $this->createNewEntryInTheDatabase();

    /* Inserts the new patterns into the DB and looks up the already existing
    ** patterns in the DB. Returns an array with the IDs of the submitted patterns */
    $patternIds = $this->lookupPatternIDsAndInsertNewPatterns($_FILES['patterns']);

    $curl = $this->initCURL();
    ...
    $this->closeCURL($curl);

    return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'jobs', 'action' => 'submit'));
}

...

private function lookupPatternIDsAndInsertNewPatterns($patternsFile) {
    $patternIDs = null;

    /* One element for each row */
    $patternsArray = $this->convertUploadedCSVFileIntoArray(
        $patternsFile, $this->CSV->getDelimiter(),
        $this->CSV->getEnclosure(), $this->CSV->getEscape());

    ...

    return $patternIDs;
}

/* Returns the patterns from the CSV file in an array */
private function convertUploadedCSVFileIntoArray(
    $patternsFile, $delimiter, $enclosure, $escape) {
    $patternsArray = file($patternsFile['tmp_name']);
    $patterns = null;
    foreach ($patternsArray as $pattern)
        $patterns[] = str_getcsv(
            $pattern,
            $delimiter,
            $enclosure,
            $escape);

    return $patterns;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've updated my question with a small code snippet, but I think the other controller parts are not relevant for now. As I've updated the question, I basically would like to test with the content of the uploaded file.

Comment: You're right, I've added information about my test I've written so far for this part, but my controller is not relevant for my question now.

Comment: Last attempt. If you want help testing x - you need to show x. No controller code means there can be no answer. -1

Comment: I've already said what I want to test.
HOW to mock/imitate an uploaded file with POST method to a given action which does some work with the passed input file.
I still don't see why would it be relevant for anybody, that what does exactly my controller's given action do with my uploaded file.

Comment: It's relevant because you have [an x/y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can't do what you're asking because [move_uploaded_file won't work with fake data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402765/how-can-i-write-tests-for-file-upload-in-php) - which means the very first thing to do to help you is determine _if_ your controller action is testable at all. It either is testable because you already thought about this; isn't testable because it's all in one method or worse is testable because it's fundamentally insecure and should be rewritten.

Comment: I've added the controller's code snippet to the question, thanks in advance if you can take a look at it.

Comment: Well it's not very pretty but you can test that. However, as I alluded earlier it's insecure because there are no checks that the file is infact an upload just. This: `$patternsArray = file($patternsFile['tmp_name']);` Will work with a file upload OR a fabricated post request pointing at anything in the file system (which is what your test case will do); All of that logic should be in a model.